# how do I write a code to identify points on a graph made in excel?

Tags: python, spyder

I am materials engineer trying to use coding for a certain project. I calculated of the values for the project in excel and plotted a graph. the graph has 4 quadrants and boundary conditions. the values fall in different quadrants and each quadrant is a regime and has a different formula for further calculations. instead of doing individual assessment of each point on where it lies in the graph (under which regime) I would like to write a code in python or spyder to find regime associated with each point in the graph. I am new to coding and have tried simple calulations but this seems a bit complicated for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sadly (for you), SO is not a tutorials site and we can't teach you coding basics. It is intended to help with existing code segments that produce errors or wrong outputs. You should make some research on your own (A good place to start is [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)), probably start with some easier projects, and ask here once you have some code. See [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

To read excel files, check out the [Pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/) and it's `read_excel` or `read_csv` functions. It has a lot of built in functions for data processing, but you could just loop over your points and write the test conditions. In addition, you can use `numpy` to handle arrays. For plotting, there is `matplotlib`. I think it's worth investing the time and effort to learn these, they will help you a lot down the road.